# D3 colors for categories and similar colors for every subcategory

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data structure like:

```
{
  id: X
  subId: Y
}
```

The id should decide what kind of color (greenish, blueish, redish, yellowish) it should be. `d3.scale.category10()` should be enough.

From this color I would like to have 'subcolors' (different blues, different greens) for every subId (the more different they look, the better - however, seeing the difference between id's is more important than seeing the difference between subIds).

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: Use [`.brighter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors#rgb_brighter) (or `.darker()`) on the colour of the category.

Comment: This will turn my color to black after 3-4 steps, thus, is not very good for many different subIds

Comment: Depends on the argument you specify.

Comment: hm, could you explain? if I pass any number greater than 4 it basically is the same return value (darker(4) == darker(5) == darker(6)). Am I using it right with d3.hsl(d3.scale.category10(id)).brighter(subId % 20) to get 20 different colors?

Comment: thanks, your answer is sufficient! i just figured out that you can type in any floating point number as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use D3's [`.brighter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors#rgb_brighter) and/or `.darker()` functions to modify the colours you get from the scale for the categories. Note that both functions take an argument that allows you to control how much brighter/darker the colours get (values less than 1).